# How do I execute code before update the content?

Tags: nodes, hooks

How do I execute code before updating nodes?

I am looking for a hook to use in a custom module.

I have created a content type. What I need to do is execute a hook before updating any content. I want to keep the history of every content, so I want to execute some code before updating, which will compare previous and currently update record. If there is any change, I want to insert it in another table.

I also want to show that history on the content detail page.

Comment: Both of the current answers are correct.  However, there are some nuanced differences between the different hooks because they get called at different parts in the `node_save()` process.  You really need to read the docs (and the code for `node_save()`) to understand this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the [Hook Post Action](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_post_action) module because it's execute after the action. So you know that the node is really updated.

> So this module introduces several new Drupal hooks to overcome this
> limitation
>
> - hook_entity_postsave
> - hook_entity_postinsert
> - hook_entity_postupdate
> - hook_entity_postdelete
> - hook_node_postsave
> - hook_node_postinsert
> - hook_node_postupdate
> - hook_node_postdelete

But, if you want you can use the [hook_node_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7.x).

To show info in the node page you can use the [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) module.

> "Eva" is short for "Entity Views Attachment;" it provides a Views
> display plugin that allows the output of a View to be attached to the
> content of any Drupal entity. The body of a node or comment, the
> profile of a user account, or the listing page for a Taxonomy term are
> all examples of entity content.

Answer (score 5):

I think, [`hook_node_presave`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x) would help for your requirement. Act on a node being inserted or updated. This hook is invoked from [`node_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7.x) before the node is saved to the database.

Answer (score 2):

The hooks that are called before Drupal saves the node in the database are the following ones (in the order from the first to the last one):

- [`hook_field_attach_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_presave/7.x)
- [`hook_node_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x)
- [`hook_entity_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/7.x)

They are all equivalent, since they get the object being saved.

Keep in mind that, since `node_save()` is using a database transaction, you cannot be sure the data is rolled back, or effectively saved in the database, until the last database operation is not completed.